# 2 internal pdfviewers in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, preview

Merry Christmas!

I use TeXstudio on Windows 10 for writing 2 texts simultaneously. So I need to see simultaneously their previews.

[image]

Can anyone help me for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is impossible, just a challenge. You can have as many separate TeXstudio internal windows as your screens and system memory allow. Here are 3 where two are set to one TeX file and the other is to a second TeX file, there are a few steps necessary and several quirky limitations, you will need to test for yourself, see below

[image]

1) you need to switch the internal viewer from "Embedded" to "Windowed"

2) you need to select Window > New window

Note that the first window will be the one that is used for **all files when compiled (or viewed)**

3) to stop the second window from tracking those jumps from tex to tex you need to "Configure" > *Ignore for synchronisation* (as shown in my screen shot) **HOWEVER NOTE THAT** the contents **WILL** synchronise with the main window changes at each compile !

I have not yet found a way to store window settings per session and it can take a couple of seconds to set a group of windows for a bunch of sub files but it is worth it for a long session.

Answer (score 3):

Go into the configuration (option->Configure) and then choose in Build->external pdfviewer

Comment: Thanks! Good advice! Also I prefer internal pdfviewers. Is it possible to have 2 internals pdfviewers?

Comment: No, not possible